# How do I style the tooltip that displays element title on hover?

Tags: theming, tooltips

## Background

I am building a custom Drupal theme for my site. For the most part, the styling is pretty straight forward, but I am struggling to find what js or css controls what appears to be a tooltip which appears under the mouse when you hover over elements with a title attribute (the grey rectangle):

[image]

## Attempts

I tried searching for it, but I wasn't able to find anything on stack overflow/exchange that are actually related to Drupal, or otherwise helped me to resolve the issue.

After this, I tried to use the developer tools in chrome to see if I could find it this way. I tried searching the event listeners, but there was a lot of listeners present and I wasn't able to narrow it down this way either.

Besides that, I crawled the core scripts/styling to see if I could find it manually.

How do I select this in the CSS and style it?

Comment: Are you sure it’s definitely JS/CSS and not the browser’s standard behaviour? I see an identical hint in Brave on any site I hover over a link with a title attribute, for example

Comment: I am not sure actually. I am not familiar with this behaviour and thought much of the browser's default styling was disabled with my normalize css. I didn't know that browsers can have default behaviour that extends beyond custom css. Thanks for pointing this out, I will look into this to see if that is what it is.

Comment: Browser will individually show the title attribute on hover. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag for solutions